# Is it possible to insert and fetch many (100,000) records in SQlite table at a time?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have user details table which contains thousands of records and i want to store this into sqlite db so that i can access it any time. But i'm not sure that sqlite db will handle thousands of records using cursor.

Comment: Sqlite can handle more that this capacity, but will your device supports same !!. Each device has different memory,RAM & ROM configuration.

Comment: right now i have tried with 2 thousand records, and im fetching those records from server and storing it in sqlite but it takes long time.

Comment: SQLite can handle storage. It's upto the developer to sensibly fetch only the data that is needed so that fewer resources are used.

Comment: So find out why/where it is slow and fix it ..

Comment: Even if you have 100,000 records, Showing them all at the same time, like in a list view, will only make the end user's task more intense. If you have these many records, you must have some filters/search options made available to the user so that the user can focus on a set of records at a time. The filter option can be By Name, By Count or any thing that best suits your DB structure. By this method, You will be able to provide a better user experience, and also you will have a smaller number of records to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

dont fetch all the record at once. first fetch like 100 or 200 or 500 records. then detect when the user is at bottom of the list(lets say) then fetch another 100 or more records or simply you can add button at the bottom title with "load more" then fetch more records. dont get all the records at once. when user required records then fetch. like this it will not make any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any detail about the problem that you try to solve. So every answer of your question will be vague.

If you show  part of the data in db, implementing paging mechanism will be better.

If you interpret the data in db, maybe storing these data in mobile storage is wrong choice and maybe it is time to move server and do what is required in that server and provide required data to android over network.

I hope it is helpful for you

Comment: i have the same problem where i have 2.6 million records storing a number and I need to calculate exponential moving average, and other similar metrics that need all the data to produce an accurate result

Answer (score 0):

android sqlite can handle very big db no need to worry but you must see to that your app should not load so slow and feel unpleasant to user
you can answer your question using developers guide 
best place to study in detail 
link:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not fetch and add records at a time as there because SqlStatement class is not a thread safe class,it can give you error. So before mdoing insert and fetch you should make it synchronize .